# Create NuGet Server on IIS 5.1

Tags: nuget, iis-5, nuget-server

I'm wanting to create a remote NuGet server.  I've followed the instructions here:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Everything works when I F5 it and look at it in debug mode...  So then I decided to publish to the remote server.

And everything works great EXCEPT... when I click the 'here' link from the default page to look at the package feed... I get a 404 error.  I did NOT get this error in debug mode.

I'm assuming it's not serving the feed correctly.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to get the same server running on a IIS 5 site as well, but no matter what settings I seemed to change I couldn't get it to work.

Instead, I ended up using [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) which comes with its own built-in web server and is free.

Hope this helps,

-Lonnie

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I'm just not finding a way to get it to work on IIS... but ProGet was a great solution!  Thanks!